# Scheme: Using apply on a list of tuples

Tags: scheme, apply

How do I use apply in Scheme to multiply the first element of each tuple by a number?

Example, if my list x = `( (1 2) (3 4) )`

I want to do something like: `(apply * 2 (car x))` so that it would return
`( (2 2) (6 4) )`.

Comment: You probably want to use `map`, not `apply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that I don't think you're entirely understanding about how all these elements of Scheme fit together.

First of all, the term "tuple" is a little ambiguous. Scheme does not have any formal tuple type—it has pairs and lists. Lists are themselves built from pairs, though that is often an implementation detail when working with higher-order functions. Is your list a list of lists of two elements or a list of pairs?

Second of all, `apply` is not what you want here. The `apply` function takes a function and a list of arguments, then calls that function with the provided list as its arguments. Instead, you want `map`, which takes a list and a transformer function that is applied to each element in the list and returns the list created by applying the function to all elements in the provided list.

The easiest way to do this is with a simple lambda expression. This will work for both lists and pairs, since accessing the first element is the same in each case.

```
(map (lambda (x)
       (cons (* 2 (car x)) (cdr x)))
     '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

This calls the provided anonymous function with each element of the list, and the function returns a new pair with the first cell double that of its input value and the second cell unchanged.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'm pretty new to Scheme so thank you for clarifying the proper use for those terms!